# Finding a basis for null and column space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help computing $\mathrm{null}(A)$ and $\mathrm{col}(A)$

$$A =
 \begin{bmatrix} 
    1 & 2 & 1 & 4  \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
    -1 & 1 & -1 & \ -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I think I did $\mathrm{null}(A)$ correctly. I found the row reduced echelon form and found that $x_{1} = -x_{3} - 2x_{4}$ and that $x_{2} = -x_{4}$. I also found that $x_3, x_4$ are free.

So my basis for $\mathrm{null}(A)$ was

$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 \\
    0 \\
    1 \\  
    0 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
    -2 \\
   -1 \\
    0 \\  
    1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right\}.$$

I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: You calculated the null-space correctly.

Comment: ok. Thanks. I do not know how to get Col A . another question I have is what's the difference between this and span?

Comment: I am not sure what Col A is. Is it the image of the transpose of $A$ ?

Comment: The span is the vector space spanned by the row-vectors. It has dimension $2$, since the kernel has dimension $2$. (The sum of the dimensions has to be $4$ because the row vectors have $4$ components)

Comment: how can i find col A ? (basis of column space)

Comment: Show that the third and the fourth column are linear combinations of the first and second column. The first two columns form a basis for the column-space.

Comment: i do not understand i tried reading online but can not find anything about what the final answer should look like

Answer (score 3):

For the column space: note that the reduced row-echelon form of $A$ is given by
$$\mathrm{RREF}(A)=\begin{bmatrix} 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 2  \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

To find the column space of $A$, we want to look at the columns in $A$ which have leading $1$'s in $\mathrm{RREF}(A)$. Since columns one and two have leading $1$'s, then that tells us that
$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 
    1 \\
    1 \\
    -1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 
    2 \\
    1 \\
    1
\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$
forms a basis for $\mathrm{col}(A)$.

Moreover, the entries in columns three and four tell us exactly how to write said columns as a linear combination of the basis:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
    1 \\
    1 \\
    -1
\end{bmatrix}=1\begin{bmatrix} 
    1 \\
    1 \\
    -1
\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix} 
    2 \\
    1 \\
    1
\end{bmatrix},$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
    4 \\
    3 \\
    -1
\end{bmatrix}=2\begin{bmatrix} 
    1 \\
    1 \\
    -1
\end{bmatrix}+1\begin{bmatrix} 
    2 \\
    1 \\
    1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus, columns three and four are indeed in $$\mathrm{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 
    1 \\
    1 \\
    -1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 
    2 \\
    1 \\
    1
\end{bmatrix}\right\},$$ 
and $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 
    1 \\
    1 \\
    -1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 
    2 \\
    1 \\
    1
\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ is a linearly independent set (if not, $\mathrm{RREF}(A)$ would not have a leading $1$ in both of the first two columns).